# iphone avaudiofoundation sound completion in loop

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

Is it possible to force an audio file to finish playing before proceeding with code?  In the below example, I'd like an audio file to play for as many times as I have items in the array.  current it finishes the loop only playing once.  I'm using the AVAudioPlayer within the AVFoundation framework.

```
for (int i = 0; i<[Array count]; i++) {
    if ([Array objectAtIndex:i] == @"Red") {
        NSLog(@"red");
        [self.player play];
    }
    if ([Array objectAtIndex:i] == @"Blue") {
        NSLog(@"blue");
        [self.player play];
    }
    if ([Array objectAtIndex:i] == @"Green") {
        NSLog(@"green");
        [self.player play];
    }
    if ([Array objectAtIndex:i] == @"Yellow") {
        NSLog(@"yellow");
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

I also use the method audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying to test if it's finishing five times, but it only reaches this method once.

```
-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL) completed{
    if ((completed) == YES){
        NSLog(@"audio finish");
        return;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to hold the for loop in place while the audio is playing?

in theory the console should read: color->audio finish->color->audio finish->repe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can tell the AudioPlayer to play when you receive the finishedPlaying notification like:

```
int arrayIndex = 0
NSArray* array;  //initialized somewhere..


-(void)myFunction
{
  if(arrayIndex < [array length])
  {
    NSArray* colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red",@"Blue",@"Green",@"Yellow",nil];
    if( [colors indexOf:[array objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]] != NSNotFound )
    {
      NSLog( [array objectAtIndex:arrayIndex] );
      [self.player play];
    }
    arrayIndex++;
  }else{
    NSLog(@"audio finish");
  }
}

-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)     completed{
    if ((completed) == YES){
      [self myFunction];
    }
}

-(void)start_it_up
{
  arrayIndex = 0;
  [self myFunction];
}
```

Comment: I like this idea.  I'll give it a try.